# WPF update View for list with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I know that the actual way is to use an `ObservableCollection`. I want to teach someone WPF and started with an `ItemsControl` which binds to a `List<MyPoco>`. Now I'm implementing a `RemoveCommand`. What I've planned to do is something like that:

```
private void Remove(MyPoco obj) 
{
    if (MyList.Contain(obj)) 
    {
        MyList.Remove(obj);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyList));
    }
}
```

I'd have expected WPF to update the View. Why isn't that working?

I'm implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` the proper way. It's working for other properties.

Comment: It's hard to tell with that short code only. But maybe your ViewModel does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: are you implementing ```INotifyPropertyChanged```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You notify that the `MyList` property has changed, but the View did realize that it already displays that instance stored in `MyList` property and so there is no update.

You can try this code

```
private void Remove(MyPoco obj) 
{
    MyList = MyList.Where( e => e != obj ).ToList();
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyList));
}
```

Now there is a new list instance and the view will update.

Comment: If what you're saying is true, then changing the MyList property to IEnumerable and having the backing field be a List <T> should work as well.

Comment: Okay well that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @FlaGon I did not get your point. How will a different type cause a different value - it is the same reference to the instance